# SQL Server LSCopy Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs, log-shipping

Is the LSCopy job needed? Can the LSCopy job be disabled, pointing the LSRestore job to the location the Transaction logs are placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is needed. The idea is to copy the backup to the destination server and restore it so that in case of network glitch it wont break the secondary db into in consistent state. LSCopy reads and writes into the monitoring table as what files are copied to secondary and based on that the LSRestore the db.